# IF "Date field" is wrong can we put default date automatically

Tags: sql-server, if-statement

I get some data automatically from another table. The date column is a string.  I convert this column to DateTime. But sometimes the date field comes like `"01.01.0002"` or `"01.01.0202"`.
When it's happened like this I get this error:

> "SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and
>   12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM."

Is that possible to put an If statement to get date `"1/1/1753"` as default date when it comes wrong?

Comment: Try changing your date field to type `DateTime2` which has a wider range. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for the definition.

Comment: Sinan, use DateTime2 NULL instead, and after conversion you could update columns earlier than a certain date to NULL.

Comment: why don't you sanitize the input data instead ? If the string is not a valid date don't insert. You may also use `TRY_CONVERT()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

**Datetime** and **Datetime2** datatypes minimum and maximum values like as below

```
 +-----------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | DataType  |             MIN             |             MAX              |                                 STORAGE                                 |
    +-----------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | Datetime  | 1753-01-01 00:00:00.000     | 12/31/9999  12:00:00 AM      | 8 bytes                                                                 |
    | Datetime2 | 0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 | Presicion 1-2 = 6 bytes precision 3-4 = 7 bytes precision 5-7 = 8 bytes |
    +-----------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

According to these details, you can use the following conversions for your issue. If [**TRY_CAST**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) can not convert the DateTime it returns NULL expression so we will change this **NULL** value with "**1753-01-01**"

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(ISNULL(TRY_CAST('01.01.0002' AS DATETIME), '1753-01-01') AS DATETIME) DateTime_Convert, 
       TRY_CAST('01.01.0002' AS DATETIME2) AS DateTime2_Convert;
```

Result:

**Updated resultset**

```
+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
|    DateTime_Convert     |      DateTime2_Convert      |
+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 1753-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0002-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is really the solution, `01.01.0002` and `01.01.0202` just seem like garbage that doesn't need preserving. There are other benefits of `Datetime2 ` but real world use cases that require dates before 1753 are uncommon and doesn't sound like the OP has one.

Comment: "Is that possible to put an If statement to get date "1/1/1753" as default date when it comes wrong" If this is the question TRY_CAST and ISNULL could be helpful to handle this problem. So I have given two options for this problem.

Comment: I don't think this information is correct. Why would casting '01.01.0002' as datetime2 would give 1252-01-01 at all?????

Comment: @CetinBasoz you are so right. I have just updated the resultset of the conversion query.